# Preparing Data in python, one column separed in two by character

Tags: python, pandas, signals, data-conversion

I have a file exported from `spike2` as `.txt` that contains two signals of the same length. I import the files with `pandas.read_cvs`.
The file is made of 19 lines of characters then start the values of my signals in one column. In the middle there are two lines of character and start the values of my second signal. Like this schema :

```
"text'.........."
"text'.........."
...
...
"text'.........."
"text'.........."
1.5
2.71
...
...
...
0.56
"text'.........."
1.98
0.567
...
...
...
6.89
```

I would like to automatically separate my two signals to plot them one on top of the other (sharing x axis) and plot the spectrogram of each one.

But until now I couldn't separate easily my two signals.

Comment: Do you **really** want to separate them in an *overbearingly domineering manner*?  Did you mean automatically?

Comment: I just don't want to have to count manually how many line there is in the column for the first signal...

Comment: yep, sorry, i'hadn't see it...

Comment: I couldn't resists, it seemed too funny, and you may *feel* like that if the code is giving you trouble. lol. I know I have felt like that before with code :) See my answer below to give you a start. This is a perfect example of [data munging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_wrangling)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Pandas [Data Munging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_wrangling) Fun

You can accomplish this in a few steps:

1. Use the [`skiprows=`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html?highlight=skiprows) and [`header=None`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html?highlight=header) parameters for [`pd.read_csv()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) to ignore the first few rows when you read the file.
2. Remove all text rows with [`pd.to_numeric()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) and [`df.dropna()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html).
3. Split half way down and place into another column with `len(df)/2` [slicing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing) followed by [`pd.concat()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html).
4. Assuming you have [`matplotlib`](http://matplotlib.org), just call [`df.plot()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) to display.

Example:

```
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
from cStringIO import StringIO

text_file = '''text line
text line
text line
text line
text line
text line
1.5
2.71
0.567
2.71
2.71
0.56
text line
1.98
0.567
1.98
2.71
0.56
6.89'''

# Read in data with, separate data with newline (\n) and skip the first n lines
# StringIO(text_file) is for example only
# Normally, you would use pd.read_csv('/path/to/file.csv', ...)
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text_file), sep='\n', header=None, skiprows=6)
print 'Two signals:'
print df
print

print 'Force to numbers:'
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
print df
print

print 'Remove NaNs:'
df = df.dropna().reset_index().drop('index', 1)
print df
print

# You should have 2 equal length signals, one after the other, so split half way
print 'Split into two columns:'
s1 = df[:len(df)/2].reset_index().drop('index', 1)
s2 = df[len(df)/2:].reset_index().drop('index', 1)
df = pd.concat([s1, s2], axis=1)
df.columns = ['sig1', 'sig2']
print df
print

# Plot, assuming you have matplotlib library
df.plot()
```

---

```
Two signals:
            0
0         1.5
1        2.71
2       0.567
3        2.71
4        2.71
5        0.56
6   text line
7        1.98
8       0.567
9        1.98
10       2.71
11       0.56
12       6.89

Force to numbers:
        0
0   1.500
1   2.710
2   0.567
3   2.710
4   2.710
5   0.560
6     NaN
7   1.980
8   0.567
9   1.980
10  2.710
11  0.560
12  6.890

Remove NaNs:
        0
0   1.500
1   2.710
2   0.567
3   2.710
4   2.710
5   0.560
6   1.980
7   0.567
8   1.980
9   2.710
10  0.560
11  6.890

Split into two columns:
    sig1   sig2
0  1.500  1.980
1  2.710  0.567
2  0.567  1.980
3  2.710  2.710
4  2.710  0.560
5  0.560  6.890
```

---

[image: df plot]

The spectrogram will have to wait...

Comment: Awesome!  The spectrogram should almost be another question.  Now that you have the data in a computable form, you should be able to find other spectrogram examples out there on SO or google.